# Cron syntax for every 30 minutes | gitlab

Tags: linux, cron

I am looking for cron syntax to execute:-
1- For every 30 minutes daily
2- From 7:00 AM to 1:00 AM(Midnight)

After reading blogs I could only manage to get `*/30 * * * *` this.

Comment: Use this: https://crontab.guru/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be an option:

```
*/30 7-23,0-1 * * *
```

As long as you can only set consecutive hours from 0h to 23h and you need to run from 7am to 1am I think it fits your needs, despite using two hourly-based conditions in the same job.